# How to start and run two background services at the same time?

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask

I want to click the 'start' button so that the app can start and run two services at the same time.
I have created two services named `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. For each service, I've
created a runnable method (in `onStartCommand`) to escape the ANR problem. I also created a start button, so that when I click the start button, I hope that `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` can start at exactly the same time, or in other words, synchronize.

I've tried many ways. The first attempt is simply to start the services one by one, but that failed:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceA.class);
        startService(intent1);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceB.class);
        startService(intent2);

    }
});
```

Then I am planning to try `AsyncTask`, but as the services are run in the background with a handler, if I use `AsyncTask` it will create another background handler, which is not applicable. Do you have any suggestions to run two services in one button click at exactly the same time?

Comment: not. if there's only one processor, it can only perform one task at the time. if there are multiple processors ... maybe you can use that, but not sure how (or why). there 's just a very limited time between the two starting up, what is the problem with that?

Comment: `exactly the same time` you can never expect this.

Comment: Hi Mr.Stultuske, the problems is that I try to use above way, but it will only run serviceA, I hope to put serviceA and serviceB in one click event, I think this might concerns about the threading synchronize problem, but I don't know any solutions about that due to my limited experience in android development, is it possible to use executeOnexecuter to do this job?   thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into java concurrency and multi-threading. If you wish to run the two methods side by side, you must use threads...

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        codeHereWillRunConcurrentlyWithMainThread();
    }
});
thread1.start();

Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        codeHereWillAlsoRunConcurrentlyWithMainThread();
    }
});
thread2.start();
```

However, if your two threads are supposed to be working together, you need to look up how to use java's built in "synchronize" keyword. It is used to prevent deadlocks in multi-threaded concurrent environments and prevent a variable/variables from being modified while other threads are operating on said variable/variables.

For more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/
http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Comment: Hi Joe D, thanks for your answer.  the problems is serviceA is used to collect sensor data on smartphone and serviceB is used to collect BLE device near to smartphone, so I have to combine this two service into one single click event so that I can collect sensor data and BLE device at the same time finally,  I also considering to use Asynctask executeOnexecutor to do this work but I am not sure if it works due to my poor experience with android studio. or if you have any more suggestions about that?   finally, I really appreciate your kindness help!!!

Comment: Not a problem man. You are definitely looking for asynchronous calls. Try the AsyncTask. Or similarly, synchronize the methods in the threads to a variable which locks them the current thread.